# 'GenericApiView' object has no attribute 'update' in my views.py file

Tags: python, django

The .update function is not suppporting to this genericApiView in my view.py file it gives me an error message 'GenericApiView' object has no attribute 'update' .

```
class GenericApiView(generics.GenericAPIView,mixins.ListModelMixin,
           mixins.CreateModelMixin,mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    serializer_class=ArticleSerializer
    queryset=Article.objects.all()
    lookup_field='id'
    authentication_classes=[SessionAuthentication,BaseAuthentication]
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self,request, id=None):
        if id:
            return self.retrieve(request)
        else:
            return  self.list(request)

    def post(self,request,id):
        return self.create(request,id)
# Error in this function 
    def put(self,request,id):
        return self.update(request,id)    

    def delete(self,request,id=None):
        return self.destroy(request,id)
```

Comment: Put the mixins *before* the `GenericAPIView`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem not working yet

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem not working yet

Comment: You are calling `self.update()` and not inheriting from `mixins.UpdateModelMixin`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `GenericApiView` class not inheriting from `mixins.UpdateModelMixin`, and when `put` method calls `self.update()` it's causing an `AttributeError`. Possible solution:

```py
class GenericApiView(generics.GenericAPIView,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin):  # added the mixin
    # ...
```